# Draw Japanese characters using openCV in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, utf-8

I'm using Python 2.7.14 and openCV to draw frames captured from a video with text next to it, this text is written in Japanese.
But the problem is that I always got the result as "?????".
I searched a lot and tried solutions but none of them worked.
Is there anyway to make the following line draw the text as it is.

```
cv2.putText(frame, "電撃文庫", (left + 6, bottom - 6), font, 2.0, (255, 255, 255), 1)
```

Comment: Did you try using `unicode`s?

Comment: If you mean "電撃文庫".encode("UTF-8"), yes.

Comment: No. That is not at all what I meant.

Comment: Try `u"電撃文庫"`! If that does not help the underlying library might not have (full) unicode support.

Comment: Yes I tried this too..but got the error "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(128)
"

Comment: I seriously doubt that the Hershey fonts in OpenCV support any of the Japanese scripts. Look at the [source](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/05b15943d6a42c99e5f921b7dbaa8323f3c042c6/modules/imgproc/src/hershey_fonts.cpp) -- each line represents a character, and there are 16 variants (8 fonts, normal and italic).

Comment: So..what should I do to support such characters?

Comment: Not sure, this is not a problem I had to deal with so far :) | If you have Qt available and your OpenCV was built with support for it, there are some [highgui extensions](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/dc/d46/group__highgui__qt.html#ga4e2751b94f709c848f0658d78007e449) that may let you load a Unicode font and display what you need. Or perhaps using something like freetype to render the text to the image buffer.

Comment: Or perhaps if there's a limited number of texts you need to display, pre-render them as images using some tool that can do that (a decent image editor, or a screenshot of a word-processor, if we're gonna take the easy way) and them copy those into the image instead of writing text.